# How to throttle a server request with Rxjs 5?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to create a function to make a HTTP PUT request in the server but only once every 500ms with the last call parameters if the function is called multiple times within that interval and cancel the last request if it is still in progress.

I researched and came up with this solution:

```
const { Observable } = require('rxjs/Observable')
const { Subject } = require('rxjs/Subject')
const { switchMap, auditTime } = require('rxjs/operators')

// Simulate HTTP request
function makeRequest (val) {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    console.log('Request:', val);
    observer.next(val);
    observer.complete();
  });
}

const toUpdateStream = new Subject();
const notifier$ = toUpdateStream.pipe(
  auditTime(500),
  switchMap(val => makeRequest(val))
);


function updateThrottle (val) {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    const lastUpdate$ = notifier$.subscribe(res => {
      observer.next(res);
      observer.complete();
      lastUpdate$.unsubscribe();
    });
    toUpdateStream.next(val);
  });
}

// Try to update 3 times with different parameters
updateThrottle(10).subscribe(val => { console.log('1:', val); });
updateThrottle(20).subscribe(val => { console.log('2:', val); });
updateThrottle(30).subscribe(val => { console.log('3:', val); });
```

The output is:

```
Request: 30
1: 30
Request: 30
2: 30
Request: 30
3: 30
```

The problem is that I need the Request only being called once with 30, not every time.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some stuff I end up with this final solution:

```
const { Observable } = require('rxjs/Observable')
const { Subject } = require('rxjs/Subject')
const { auditTime, switchMap } = require('rxjs/operators')

// Simulate log with timestamp
const log = msg => {
  const d = new Date();
  console.log(d.getSeconds() +'.'+ d.getMilliseconds() +' - '+ msg);
}

// Simulate HTTP request that takes 750ms
function makeRequest (val) {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      log('Request: '+ val);
      observer.next('R'+ val);  // Mock the HTTP response
      observer.complete();
    }, 750);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  });
}

const toUpdateStream$ = new Subject();
const updatedStream$ = new Subject();
const filter$ = toUpdateStream$.pipe(
  auditTime(500),
  switchMap(val => makeRequest(val))
);
filter$.subscribe(val => updatedStream$.next(val));

function updateThrottle (val) {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    const lastUpdate = updatedStream$.subscribe(res => {
      observer.next(res);
      observer.complete();
      lastUpdate.unsubscribe();
    });
    toUpdateStream$.next(val);
  });
}

log('Start');

// Try 3 requests and the last one (the 30) gets processed
updateThrottle(10).subscribe(val => log('1: '+ val));
updateThrottle(20).subscribe(val => log('2: '+ val));
updateThrottle(30).subscribe(val => log('3: '+ val));

// Try to make more requests when the current one isn't finished
setTimeout(() => {
  // This one cancels the last one
  updateThrottle(40).subscribe(val => log('4: '+ val));
  updateThrottle(50).subscribe(val => log('5: '+ val));
  updateThrottle(60).subscribe(val => log('6: '+ val)); // This gets processed
}, 600);
```

And the logs:

```
43.394 - Start
45.275 - Request: 60
45.277 - 1: R60
45.277 - 2: R60
45.278 - 3: R60
45.278 - 4: R60
45.278 - 5: R60
45.278 - 6: R60
```

Which should only make one request with the last parameters and return that to the listeners.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to pass values to `auditTime` only if they have changed from the previous emission. The [`pairwise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pairwise) operator is good for this use-case.

```
const notifier$ = toUpdateStream.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  pairwise(), // Emit the previous and current search options
  filter(([oldSearch, newSearch]) => oldSearch !== newSearch),
  map(([oldSearch, newSearch]) => newSearch),
  auditTime(500),
  switchMap(val => makeRequest(val))
);
```

Instead of `pairwise()` you can also use `bufferCount(2, 1)`, it'll do the same thing.

Comment: After making the changes the request is now made 2 times. The idea is to make the request only once every 500ms if it was called multiple times even if it is the same. Do you know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: I see, you'll need to "initialize" the `pariwise()` with a default emission from `startWith(null)`, see my update.